# cron-job.org url conversion problem for cron

Tags: php, cron

Every time when cron-job.org runs my script the URL which is inside the script converts.
Like:
url used inside script:

```
https://example.com?data1=ab&data2=cd
```

converted to:

```
https://example.com?data1=ab&ampdata2=cd
```

so, script runs as useless.
I used file_get_contents() function.
How it can be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

N.B: The conversion not occurring when I manually run it.
I already used some URL coding and html entity methods, but not worked for cron-job.org.

Comment: Can you post the script?

Comment: make sure you are not adding a space after & sign.

Comment: @Aeyzaz Khan. No I did not add space after & sign.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. I will try. But it worked when I manually run it.